# 2 VideoViews in one LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem with placing two sets of a VideoView and a button one below another. I do it this way scrollLayout(LinearLayout(video->button->space->second video->second button)). 
**THE PROBLEM IS THAT WHEN SETTING THE SECOND VIDEO AND SOME SPACE BETWEEN IT AND THE FIRST BUTTON THE SCROLLLAYOUT BREAKS DOWN (SHOWS ITS MIDDLE INSTEAD OF THE TOP LIKE ON THE IMAGE BELOW OR SHOWS THE VIDEO INAPPROPRIATELY) AND IT HAPPENS ONLY WHEN SETTING 2 VIDEOVIEWS.** When I set an image or a textview instead of the second image IT WORKED FINE!!! BUT WITH 2 VIDEOVEIW IT DIDN'T.

[image: How it should be]

**THE PROBLEM**

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="false">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/introVideo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="KNOW MORE" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp" />

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/introVideo2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="KNOW MORE MORE" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Variations that work fine:

```
<ScrollView>
        <LinearLayout>
            <VideoView />
            <button />
            <space /> 
            <image />
            <button /> 
        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<ScrollView>
        <LinearLayout>
            <VideoView />
            <button />
            <space /> 
            <VideoView android:visibility="invisible" />
            <button /> 
        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change Space:

```
<Space
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />
```

Comment: I hope that will help you

Answer (score 0):

Try update layout as below

```
        <Space
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/introVideo2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="KNOW MORE MORE" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Here, all views height will be same

Comment: I guess I have to add something to <LinearLayout tag cuz not <space> and the second video disappeared. Should all element's inside the  <LinearLayout tag be weighted?